# ThreeJS App works well in the XDK emulator but not works on real device

Tags: javascript, three.js, intel-xdk, hybrid

my threeJS app works well in the XDK emulator

but while testing it on my real mobile device - it does not work (just a blank white page) ..

I think it's a webGL support issue or something like this ?

we have to convert our graduation project on mobile phone

what to do ?

is there another JS libraries like threeJS and works well on mobile phone ..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Crosswalk for Android](https://software.intel.com/en-us/xdk/docs/using-the-crosswalk-for-android-build-option)

I used this build option in XDK and the converted app of Three.js(r71) worked just fine on mobile devices.